# how to add set of string to String Array

Tags: java

I have a method called `entry.getKey()` which returns list of strings in a `for` loop.

```
entry.getKey()-->Linux|32 Bit|Chrome   
entry.getKey()-->Linux|64 Bit|IE   
entry.getKey()-->Windows 7|32 Bit|Firefox
```

like

```
String s = new String[] {entry.getKey()};
```

I want add those all strings in a array...ex : `String[]`

Comment: `String[] keys = map.keySet().toArray(new String[map.size()]);`

Comment: Can you show us the signature of `getKey()`. I'm confused as to what it does exactly. Does it return a list of strings? Does it return a  new string every time you call it? What type is `entry`?

Comment: @duncan : it returns a new string every time. i can store String list = entry.getKey(); which returns a new string in a loop.....and i want to add all those new strings into a string array(ex : String[])

Comment: @kirankumar So does it return `null` when it's out of strings?

Answer (score 0):

```
String[] s = entry.getKey().split("|");
```

Comment: yea, copy/paste mistake (i used his example). i update.

Comment: hmm, seems like one of the answer misunderstood the question! As I understand, getKey `returns list of strings`

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you have an unknown number of strings to add to an array. The typical way to do this is to add them to a list, then convert this to an array.

For example, assuming your method returns `null` when out of strings:

```
String s;
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
while ((s = entry.getKey()) != null) {
  list.add(s);
}
String[] array = list.toArray(new String[0]);
```